# determine whether the binary operation * under $ℝ$ is associative and commutative for $a * b =$ $\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $\ast$ be a binary operation on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $$ a\ast b := \sqrt[3]{a^3 + b^3}. $$
>   Is $\ast$ associative and commutative?

I tried to apply the concepts of commutative and associative groups, but the answers are probably all wrong.  My attempt is as follows:

**Commutativity:**

\begin{align}
&a * b =\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3} \quad\text{and}\quad b * a =\sqrt[3]{b^3+a^3} \\
&\qquad \implies a*b = b*a.
\end{align}

***Associativity:***

$$
(a * b)*c = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}+c^3}\quad\text{and}\quad a*(b*c) = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{b^3+c^3}+a^3}
$$

Comment: What's wrong in what you have written? It seems fine up till here.Now you need to ask if the operation is associative or not.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I think the proof for the associative is wrong.

Comment: I believe the answer you've accepted is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach to associativity is wrong - you've missed an exponent. Your operation is defined by $$x*y=\sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}.$$ So setting $x=a*b$ and $y=c$, we get

$$(a*b)*c=\sqrt[3]{(a*b)^{\color{red}{3}}+c^3}=\sqrt[3]{(\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3})^{\color{red}{3}}+c^3}.$$ Note the red exponents, and contrast that with what you've written.

Now we can simplify things a lot - $(\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3})^{\color{red}{3}}$ is just $a^3+b^3$! So in fact we have $$(a*b)*c=\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3}.$$ Now, compute $a*(b*c)$ (paying attention to the exponent issue above) and compare!

Answer (score 4):

More generally, if $\star$ is a binary operation on $A$, and $f:B\to A$ is a bijection, then we define binary operation $\star_f$ on $B$ as:

$$b_1\star_f b_2 = f^{-1}(f(b_1)\star f(b_2))$$

Then $\star$ is commutative (associative) if and only if $\star_f$ is commutative (respectively, associative.)

In your case, $A=B=\mathbb R$, $\star$ is addition, and $f(x)=x^3$ is the bijection.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof of commutativity is correct.

Edit:

I have made the same mistake as you did. $*$ is indeed associative, as you can see:

\begin{align}(a * b) * c &= \sqrt[3]{(a*b)^3 + c^3} \\
&= \sqrt[3]{\left(\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}\right)^3 + c^3} \\
&= \sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3}\\
&=\sqrt[3]{a^3+\left(\sqrt[3]{b^3+c^3}\right)^3} \\
&= \sqrt[3]{a^3 + (b*c)^3} \\
&= a*(b*c)
\end{align}

Comment: This is still incorrect, since you (like the OP) have forgotten a "cubed." (See my answer.)

Comment: It's associative...you missed the exponent three

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, thanks. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

It's associative...

$(a*b)*c=\sqrt[3]{(a*b)^{{3}}+c^3}=\sqrt[3]{(\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3})^{3}+c^3}=\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3}$

It's easier and better posing $d=a*b$

$(a*b)*c=d*c$

Then we got

$d*c=\sqrt[3]{(d)^{{3}}+c^3}=\sqrt[3]{(a*b)^{{3}}+c^3}$

$\sqrt[3]{(a*b)^{{3}}+c^3}=\sqrt[3]{(\sqrt[3] {a^3+b^3)})^3+c^3}=\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3}$